# Transferring a site's page is showing a blank page

Tags: aspx, web-part-page

Here is my scenario, I thought this should be straightforward:

1. Go to my site's Pages list under View All Site Content.
2. Download a copy of the .aspx web part page that I want to transfer to another site.
3. Go to the destination site's Pages list, click "Add New Item"
4. Upload the .aspx web part page that I just saved for transfer
5. Click on the link to the newly uploaded page to see the content: **there is nothing on the page!**

Why might this be happening? Is there some kind of compatibility issue with the content of my page? The contents of the page are list views, default SP web parts, and a content editor web part, and the list does exist on the destination site as well. Also, both sites are the same SharePoint version, Enterprise 2010, albeit separate farm installations on a separate server.

Interesting to note, though, is that the templates that the pages are using are named slightly different on each site:

Source template was created as: "(Page)TwoColumnGeneralLayout.aspx"

Destination template was created as: "(Administrative Task)TwoColumnGeneralLayout.aspx"

These are custom templates. Perhaps that makes a difference if it is transferable or not.

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506845/copy-webpart-page-aspx-page-with-web-parts but am not sure how exactly to do this "copy-pasting" into a whole other SP environment

Comment: please state exactly what you do when you "Download a copy of the .aspx web part page..." in step 2. Can you open the file in a text editor? Does it appear to have web parts defined?

Comment: Sure, I go to the list item's dropdown menu (edit menu on the "Name" column) and click "Send To -> Download a Copy" to get the .aspx file. Now that you mention it, when I open it in a text editor it doesn't seem to have my content inside it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason this won't work is that List Views reference the lists by ID not name, and the IDs will be different across different site collections.

Comment: Fair enough, but why wouldn't other web parts show, like the default Announcements view, or a CEWP, for example? The page I copied over is completely blank.

Comment: The "Default Announcements view" is a ListViewWebPart, and references the default Announcements list by id, not name. Not sure about the CEWP. Have you opened the page you copied in SP Designer?

Comment: Just tried opening the aspx page in SP Designer from the "Pages" document library of the site. It wouldn't let me open it in SPD, but it said I could edit it from the browser (selecting this does show the web parts of the page in IE)

Comment: I know I've seen that message about not being able to edit a page in SPD before, but I can't seem to replicate it. If you *could* open it in SPD, I would recommend copying the contents of that page into the contents of a new page on your destination site, and locating and changing list IDs as necessary. What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: So when I go to the aspx file in SPD and click "Edit File", I get "This page cannot be edited in SharePoint Designer. You can edit the content in the browser, or edit the corresponding page layout in SharePoint Designer." I don't think I want to edit the page layout, though...

Comment: Googling that error message gives me this page: http://sharepointsource123.blogspot.com/2012/06/this-page-cannot-be-edited-in.html - I have not tested though!

Comment: Thanks for finding that nice workaround. I was able to edit the page and I'm testing it now.

Comment: I've come to a conclusion on this: it's not practical to transfer a page this way. Your suggestion is technically correct, but trying to paste the contents doesn't work because the list IDs aren't matching up like you say. The only solution I see is to just re-create the page instead of wasting time battling with SP Designer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.